# Is it possible to use the `nopush` attribute in the `<link>` tag or it is just possible via link header?

Tags: hyperlink, http2, server-push

//1- link header

```
Link: </app/style.css>; rel=preload; as=style; nopush
```

//2- regular link

```
<link href="/app/style.css" rel="preload" 
as="style"  nopush />
```

Is the second code valid? Will it prevent the server to auto push the style.css file?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of any webserver which pushes resources based on `<link href...>` tags in HTML. As far as I’m aware, those that do use the preload method to indicate a push, only allow it using the HTTP Link method.

So there is no need to include the `nopush` attribute on `<link href...>` tags. If your webserver or other web infrastructure (e.g. CDN) does start to support this method of push then presumably it would also support the `nopush` attribute, but you would need to check the documentation on this. I am sceptical that a webserver would ever implement this.